# iOS Error: Cannot retrieve data when installing app from AppStore through BranchIO

Tags: ios, branch.io

When the app is not installed, the browser leads me to the deep views of BranchIO. There is a popup ask me to **Open in AppStore**. If I press OK and go with the flow to install the app, I cannot retrieve data from BranchIO. Otherwise, if i press cancel then press the **Open the app** button to install the app from AppStore, everything works fine. 
Here is the pic: https://d.pr/free/i/dlGuY1

Comment: Could you please share the link with which you are testing this?

Comment: [https://go.lezsingles.ignite.technology/34739680] Here it is. The numeric part is what I want to retrieve. @KartikShandilya